# Access invisible columns in a Datagridview (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, datagridview

I'm showing some data in a `DataGridView` using a list which I get from the Entity Framework. In this grid I set some database columns like the `id` to invisible.

When the user clicks on the gridview I need to know which object was clicked for further steps, the problem I cannot get the `id` column, neither through:

```
datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value // here I get only visible cells
```

nor through:

```
datagridview1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem
```

It seems that through setting some columns to invisible the objects attached have anonymous types

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You could e.g. use the `.Tag` property on each `DataGridRow` to capture the `id` value

Comment: i thought its a standart process that when a row gets clicked some action needs to be taken on the rows data/object, so i assumed i missed this functionality somhow, your idea would probably work but its somehow a workarround no?

Comment: have you set the `DataPropertyName` property of id column?

Comment: @Talha: no but im talking baout a winforms app, i can not find the property on the datagridview

Comment: yeh i know, you said, you have the column 'id', i mean set the property  DataPropertyName of this column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var value = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

and it worked.

In my example column 0 is the hidden column, that contains the id property that you want to extract.

Answer (score 2):

For me it works to take the **columnName** not the **index**.

so if your column has the name "id" you could use:

```
datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw `Jakub Kaleta's  answer` that was accepted as a best solution .after i test it, seems have a problem and it's `YOU SHOULD CLICK ON TEXT DATAGIDVIEW CELL VALUE`  and it's not a pretty good!
I do it with below solution,and you can click every place of cell!

```
 private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                _RoleID = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Value));
                _RoleName = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);

            }
        }
```

it worked for me very well ;

Answer (score 0):

You could us datakeys.

List datakeys for the hidden fields.

Then you access the values with the following code.

```
GridName.DataKeys[row.RowIndex][Index of key in datakey list].ToString()
```

For instance.  Let's say your grid is named myGrid.

You have set the following datakeys:

- Address
- City
- State
- ZIPCode

Your code to access the Address would be:

```
myGrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extention:

```
public static Int32 ToInt32(this object value)
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

public static object Get(this DataGridViewRow row,string columnName)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell item in row.Cells)
        {
            if (item.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName.Equals(columnName))
            {
                return item.Value;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and call:

```
int id = gc.CurrentRow.Get("Id").ToInt32();
```